# What does the parameter of 1 mean in `listen(1)` method of socket module in python?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tcp, server, client

What does the parameter of 1 mean in the `listen(1)` method of socket. I am using the socket module in python 2.7 and I have created a basic server that I want to connect to multiple clients (all on a local machine) and transmit data between them. I know there a simpler ways of doing this but I want practice for when the clients would not all be on the same machine and may need to retrieve something from the server first so could not bypass it. I was wondering if the 1 in listen referred to the amount of connections the server would make at a single time and if not what it did mean. I really want to understand in detail how parts of the process work so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It defines the length of the backlog queue, which is the number of incoming connections that have been completed by the TCP/IP stack but not yet accepted by the application.

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the number of concurrent connections that the server can handle.